# ¿Como obtener el numero de caracteres de una celdad de un data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Necesito obtener el número de caracteres de una celda de mi `dataframe`, utilize un ciclo `for` para poder leer todas las celdas de una columna de mi data:

```
for column in hoja.iter_cols(min_col=4, max_col= 4, min_row=3, max_row= hoja.max_row):
```

Al momento de querer obtener el número de caracteres de cada celda me da error:

```
for column in hoja.iter_cols(min_col=4, max_col= 4, min_row=3, max_row= hoja.max_row):
    for cell in column:            
        longitud = (cell).str.len
```

¿Cómo hacer para que me de el numero de caracteres de cada celda?

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El concepto de celda como tal no existe en `pandas`. Por ello, para aplicar los métodos `.str` necesitas que la variable sea de tipo `pandas.Series` o `pandas.DataFrame`.

En tu caso, lo que necesitas es convertir una variable a `string`, y posteriormente llamar a `len()`:

```
for column in hoja:
    for cell in column:
        longitud = len(str(cell))
```

Pero mucho más sencillo que implementar un doble bucle anidado para esto es tratar de usar métodos propios de pandas, que posiblemente solucionen tu problema de forma matricial:

```
# Me invento un dataframe ya que no aportas el tuyo
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c'], data = [123, 456, 'aaa', 'bbbbbb'])
df['longitud'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta linea de codigo la utiliza para obtener la longitud maxima de cada columna:

```
longitudes = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).max()
```